# Error loading project cannot load module intellij idea

Tags: file, intellij-idea, module, load, project

I get an error message in IntelliJ (see screenshot) and I don't know how to fix it. I had that problem before but after restarting IntelliJ it was ok. But not this time. I try almost everything I found online as a solution but nothing worked. Bellow I attach a screenshot with the error message.

Any help would be appreciated!!!! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0PZQ.png)

Comment: Please file a ticket at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) and the sample project.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. Just delete the .idea from the base of the project and intellij will generate it again with all the files!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have to delete the offending lines from the `modules.xml` located in the `.idea` subfolder of your project directory.